# How to write a for loop for two variables to take the counts based on conditions and divide and print?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataset with columns:  audom, audomtext, has_bh_samples.  I want to get a percentage of what is gone, meaning has_bh_samples = 1 but using audom codes (1,2,3,4,...,17) which is linked to string names (bst,bls,...,sws).  I can do this very manually where I have one line per audom/audomtext.  But I'm trying to loop it so that I can run it on multiple datasets.  Something is wrong with my code below though.  The file is large but has multiple occurrences of each and has_bh_samples is coded 0 for not mined/gone and 1 for mined/gone.

```
dom = ["bst","bls","dst","esh","est","exo","gen","gns","kcr","nsb","rev","rdg","rjn","rjs","sn3","sn6","sws"]
domcode = list(range(1,18))
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.asc')

for domain, domainid in zip(dom, domcode):
    y = np.sum(df['audom']==domainid)
    x = np.sum((df['audom']==domainid)&(df['has_bh_samples']==1))
    print(f"domain code {domainid} for domain {domain} % total mined: '{0:.1%}'".format(x/y))
```

It outputs all the lines but it says 0.0% for all:

```
domain code 1 for domain bst % total mined: '0.0%'
domain code 2 for domain bls % total mined: '0.0%'
```

etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have googled and searched stackoverflow to get where I am but I think there might be something not quite right.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you dont try to concatenate all df in one single one? Do the columns value a lot

Comment: The pattern `df['audom']==domainid` in a loop iterating over `domainid` means you need a groupby so to avoid a quadratic execution. Beside using it twice make this twice slower. Not to mention `df['has_bh_samples']==1` is recomputed over and over for no reason. One you keep in mind that CPython optimize nothing (as opposed to compiled languages).

Comment: @INGI0R1AM0R1 it is in one df.  I thought I had to create identifiers to use in the loop?  Can I just use the columns in the df?

Comment: oh!  I got it!  print(f"domain code {domainid} for domain {domain} % total mined: {z*100:.2f}%")